# How to have timelimits with Netty?

Tags: java, timeout, netty, nonblocking

I am looking at using netty to implement a server for an AI bot competition. The chat example is a good start since the protocol I have designed is similar to a line based chat server, except for one major difference. The bots are asked to make a turn and have a maximum time limit to respond. If a bot fails to respond in time, the server will take a default action for that bot.

In particular I'm implementing The Resistance game. A leader will pick a team and then all the bots have to submit a yes or no vote. I want to wait until either all bots have voted or a timeout (eg. 2 seconds) occurs, in which case I will assign an action for the bots that have yet to respond.

How can I implement this using Netty?

Comment: Netty provides transport level protocol. Looks like you need to implement own protocol of session and app. levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to have a Game object running on a thread that uses CountDownLatch to wait upto the timelimit and collects all the votes from the Netty handlers. Any missing votes are given a default vote.

If I want to avoid having a thread for each game, I have built a [Fiber](https://github.com/grom358/fiber) library which provides cooperative lightweight threads. Then each Game object can be a fiber load balanced between a thread per CPU core.